# How can I use a singleton when switching/loading scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Hierarchy I have 3 objects I want to keep and to not destroy when starting a new game.
But I want to destroy them when switching back to the main menu.

The objects are : Player , Game Manager , Scene Loader

[image: Hierarchy]

On the 3 objects Player , Game Manager , Scene Loader I added to each one a script name PersistentManager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PersistentManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PersistentManager Instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The Scene Loader script that attached to Scene Loader :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool loadScene = false;

    [SerializeField]
    private int scene;
    [SerializeField]
    private Text loadingText;

    // Updates once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // If the player has pressed the space bar and a new scene is not loading yet...
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && loadScene == false)
        {
            LoadScene(scene);
        }

        // If the new scene has started loading...
        if (loadScene == true)
        {
            // ...then pulse the transparency of the loading text to let the player know that the computer is still working.
            loadingText.color = new Color(loadingText.color.r, loadingText.color.g, loadingText.color.b, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
        }
    }

    // The coroutine runs on its own at the same time as Update() and takes an integer indicating which scene to load.
    IEnumerator LoadNewScene()
    {
        // This line waits for 3 seconds before executing the next line in the coroutine.
        // This line is only necessary for this demo. The scenes are so simple that they load too fast to read the "Loading..." text.
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

        // Start an asynchronous operation to load the scene that was passed to the LoadNewScene coroutine.
        AsyncOperation async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(scene);

        // While the asynchronous operation to load the new scene is not yet complete, continue waiting until it's done.
        while (!async.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public void LoadScene(int scene)
    {
        // ...set the loadScene boolean to true to prevent loading a new scene more than once...
        loadScene = true;

        // ...change the instruction text to read "Loading..."
        loadingText.text = "Loading...";

        this.scene = scene;

        // ...and start a coroutine that will load the desired scene.
        StartCoroutine(LoadNewScene());
    }
}
```

And the Game Manager script that attached to Game Manager :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SceneLoader sceneLoader;
    public PlayerController playerController;
    public CamMouseLook camMouseLook;
    public static bool backToMainMenu = false;
    public static bool togglePauseGame;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            PauseGame();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            BackToMainMenu();
        }
    }

    public void PauseGame()
    {
        togglePauseGame = !togglePauseGame;

        if (togglePauseGame == true)
        {
            playerController.enabled = false;
            camMouseLook.enabled = false;
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            playerController.enabled = true;
            camMouseLook.enabled = true;
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }
    }

    private void BackToMainMenu()
    {
        sceneLoader.LoadScene(0);
        playerController.enabled = false;
        camMouseLook.enabled = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        backToMainMenu = true;
    }
}
```

Now when I'm running the game and then pressing the space bar for starting a new game the Main Menu scene is removed not sure why.

Before using the PersistentManager script I used on each of the 3 objects another script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DontDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (GameManager.backToMainMenu == false)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(transform);
        }
    }
}
```

That keep the 3 objects alive when starting a new game and if switching back to the main menu the problem was that the 3 objects was also in the main menu when switching back to the main menu.

So I had 6 copies of the objects. 3 in the main menu scene and 3 in the DontDestroyOnLoad scene.
That's why I'm trying to use singleton.

I want that when I'm switching back to the main menu the 3 object will not be in the main menu scene in the hierarchy only on the DontDestroyOnLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the class you are inheriting from has it's instance in the parent

`public static PersistentManager Instance { get; private set; }`

this means that the first object will go

1. Is instance null? yes
2. Set me as instance
3. Set a don't destroy on load

the other two objects will check the instance, see that it's not null because the first object is referenced, and they will destroy themselves.

In general I would advise against using singletons as much as possible, as some might consider them an anti design pattern.

However, if you still want to use one; I'm attaching here a script I used in games that are in production for multiple years with millions of users, so it's already set up against most of the edge cases we encountered.

```
#region Using

using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

#endregion

/// <summary>
///     Generic singleton Class. Extend this class to make singleton component.
///     Example:
///     <code>
/// public class Foo : GenericSingleton<Foo>
/// </code>
///     . To get the instance of Foo class, use <code>Foo.instance</code>
///     Override <code>Init()</code> method instead of using <code>Awake()</code>
///     from this class.
/// </summary>
public abstract class GenericSingleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : GenericSingleton<T>
{
    private static T _instance;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("If set to true, the gameobject will deactive on Awake")] private bool _deactivateOnLoad;
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("If set to true, the singleton will be marked as \"don't destroy on load\"")] private bool _dontDestroyOnLoad;

    private bool _isInitialized;

    public static T instance
    {
        get
        {
            // Instance required for the first time, we look for it
            if (_instance != null)
            {
                return _instance;
            }

            var instances = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<T>();
            if (instances == null || instances.Length == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            _instance = instances.FirstOrDefault(i => i.gameObject.scene.buildIndex != -1);
            if (Application.isPlaying)
            {
                _instance?.Init();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    // If no other monobehaviour request the instance in an awake function
    // executing before this one, no need to search the object.
    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance == null || !_instance || !_instance.gameObject)
        {
            _instance = (T)this;
        }
        else if (_instance != this)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Another instance of {GetType()} already exist! Destroying self...");
            Destroy(this);
            return;
        }
        _instance.Init();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This function is called when the instance is used the first time
    ///     Put all the initializations you need here, as you would do in Awake
    /// </summary>
    public void Init()
    {
        if (_isInitialized)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_dontDestroyOnLoad)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }

        if (_deactivateOnLoad)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        SceneManager.activeSceneChanged += SceneManagerOnActiveSceneChanged;

        InternalInit();
        _isInitialized = true;
    }

    private void SceneManagerOnActiveSceneChanged(Scene arg0, Scene scene)
    {
        // Sanity
        if (!instance || gameObject == null)
        {
            SceneManager.activeSceneChanged -= SceneManagerOnActiveSceneChanged;
            _instance = null;
            return;
        }

        if (_dontDestroyOnLoad)
        {
            return;
        }

        SceneManager.activeSceneChanged -= SceneManagerOnActiveSceneChanged;
        _instance = null;
    }

    protected abstract void InternalInit();

    /// Make sure the instance isn't referenced anymore when the user quit, just in case.
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        _instance = null;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Clear static listener OnDestroy
        SceneManager.activeSceneChanged -= SceneManagerOnActiveSceneChanged;

        StopAllCoroutines();
        InternalOnDestroy();
        if (_instance != this)
        {
            return;
        }
        _instance = null;
        _isInitialized = false;
    }

    protected abstract void InternalOnDestroy();
}
```

Comment: The gameObject.IsNullOrDestroyed() the IsNullOrDestroyed() method is not exist. 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrDestroyed' and no accessible extension method 'IsNullOrDestroyed' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: sorry it was using an extension method not included. I've modified the code without it, please try it again now